# Training a model on Watson Visual Recogntion

Tags: ibm-watson

I am trying to set up a project in Watson Studio (Visual Recognition). I have added Visual Recognition to the projects. Now I want to create a model and give it data to train. However, I can not create a model.

I was following this tutorial from IBMs official website (https://youtu.be/KIw_iac56Hc?t=11). At the marked timestamp, the instructor chose "Add to project" and had plenty of options to choose from. The mask I see looks very different from this, so I am unable to create and train a new model. Does anyone what is wrong? Enclosed picture shows the options I can choose from.

Kind regards
Max
[image: Options to choose from in the project in IBM Watson]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to follow the video that's in the Watson Studio docs. It's embedded in the topic, "[Setting up your Watson Studio project for Visual Recognition](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/visual-recognition-setting-up.html?audience=wdp&context=wdp)".

If you want to work directly with the APIs, go to the [Visual Recognition docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-getting-started-tutorial) in IBM Cloud. There's a tutorial that uses the APIs directly, and there are links to the API references.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check out the docs. However, the suggestion from charles gomes worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing Watson Studio service which provide entitlement for those missing options.

Click on top-right profile icon and then select "Profile and settings"
You will probably reach to this URL if you are using US region watson studio.
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/settings/apps?context=wdp

Go under Apps Tab and you should see that you are missing the watson studio service in the region you are trying this.

[image]

Please create the Watson studio service in the region you are trying this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would not have found this! It worked out for me.